# Update Jquery Dialog after it has opened up

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a jquery dialog box. I need to update the content of the dialog after I receive any ajax response. the box will be opened up first only. but the contents of the dialog should get continuously updated. I want to append new items to the already opened dialog box.

Can anyone tell me, how can I achieve this.

Update -

```
var appendTo = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "appendTo" );
// setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "appendTo", "#someElem" );
```

above code only appends the content how do i add the content

on further research I found that, the jquery documentation refers  _allowInteraction( event ) for communicating with the dialog.

how can I add a ajax method's success handler to trigger this interaction event?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "dialog box" what do you mean? Like a plugin of some sort that actually makes a div on the page? or do you mean an `alert()` box? If it's the ladder, it's not possible.

Comment: Its a jqurey dialog box, https://jqueryui.com/dialog/, Here they use  <script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script> to load the dialog. But I want to update content of this dialog after it has been loaded or opened up

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to this. It is $("#dialog").append("test");